# Why is my LinearLayout appearing on top when I constrained it to the bottom of the parent?

Tags: android

The home and search buttons in the image below are supposed to be on the bottom of the screen, but they are on top for some reason. They look correct in the XML file, but wrong on the emulator. I constrained the LinearLayout container that holds the buttons to the bottom of the parent container, but it is still appearing on top when I inflate it.
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:text="Home"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:text="Search"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I ran this code on physical device and it works as intended. @walzhe try different emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed ok but to make sure I tried your code in my project and it was working fine as expected on my emulator. I don't know why you are getting the problem but can you try out constraint layout instead.

**Here is the code for constraint layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Home"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Search"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Could I ask how you're inflating the XML file. Maybe I'm making a mistake during inflation.

Comment: I haven't used anything fancy like viewBinding, Just the usual approach.  Exp:  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 0):

Your code is okay on my emulator and phone.

Maybe you can try this:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:text="Home"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:text="Search"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

add `android:gravity="bottom"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` in the Linear Layout.